# LLD and the Linker Scripts

Tags: c, windows, clang, linker-scripts, lld

I am trying to send the linker scripts for one of the simple c program .
I tried on both on Ubuntu and Windows.

> > On Ubuntu

After some research I found out that it was taking `GNU-ld` ,so With clang command line option `-fuse-ld=lld` ,So now I linked with clang default linker `lld`

I tried with this command

`clang main.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-Map,output.map,-T Example_Linker.ld -o main`

Everything works correctly.
I got the memory map file and also able to pass linker scripts.

> > On Windows

Clang initially look for Microsoft Visual Studio Linker `link.exe` for to generate executables.

It wont support Linker scripts.

So with `-fuse-ld=lld`

I tried the below command
`clang main.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-Map,output.map,-T Example_Linker.ld -o main`

So now error thrown was

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-Map'
lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -T
```

How should I write a command so I may be able to get a memory map file and in same time I can pass Linker Scripts?

kindly help me with solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with development on Windows, but on Mac, you pass `-map` instead of `-Map`, maybe the same will work for Windows? Not sure about the linker scripts, though.

Comment: yes when I gave -map it will give map file. But when i linked with llvm linker ```lld``` nothing seems to be working.I will get the above error.

Answer (score 2):

The linker flags you write here:

```
    -Wl,-Map,output.map
```

should be

```
    -Wl,-Map=output.map
```

Comment: I get "warning ignoring unknown argument" with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same target triple as on Ubuntu.

On my Ubuntu clang outputs this information:

```
$ clang-8 --version
clang version 8.0.0-3~ubuntu18.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

So you would use the following on windows:

```
clang --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu main.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-Map=output.map,-T Example_Linker.ld -o main
```

I cannot try this, because I don't have a linker script.
You can try to change the target triple.